# Understanding how a log-log plot models an electronic component

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, regression, linear-regression

In a research paper ([available here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268469242_Absolute_Orientation_for_a_UAV_using_Celestial_Objects)) that I'm reading, there is a description of the behavior of a photo resistor used in the construction of a more complex sensor, that goes like this :

> Its resistance $R_p$ ($\text{k}\Omega$) changes along with the light illuminance $I$ ($\text{lux}$) by a $\log − \log$ relation (Fig. 4(b)) as
> $$\log  R_p = b \log \ I + \log  a$$
> with approximate values of $a = 57.55$ and $b = −0.69$.

In the paper, Fig. 4(b) show the following diagram:

[image: fig]

The diagram gives the behavior of $\log R_p$ as a function of the illuminance $I$ taking in to account the device tolerances, as given by the producer: precisely the gray band show (in logarithmic coordinates) the limit values
$$
R_{p_\text{mean}} \pm n\sigma_{ R_p}
$$ that can be assumed by the resistance of a single device from any production lot, where

- $R_{p_\text{mean}}$ is the *mean value of the statistical distribution* of the value $R_{p}$,
- $\sigma_{R_p}$ is the standard deviation of $R_{p}$, while
- $n\in\Bbb N$ is a sufficiently large integer, meaning that the probability $P\big[R_p-R_{p_\text{mean}} \notin [-n\sigma_{R_p}, +\sigma_{R_p}]\big]$ is sufficiently small (if ${R_p}$ is assumed to have a gaussian distribution, it is customarily assumed that $n\ge 1$)

What I would like understand is how, from the data represented Fig. 4(b), the authors could get the above model formula for ${R_p}$ and the values of $a = 57.55$ and $b = −0.69$.

Comment: You'll have to provide more context. A link to the research paper would be a nice start.

Comment: https://sci-hub.se/10.2514/6.2013-5145 Here is the research paper. The formula is at the bottom of page 4.  Fig. 4(b) is on page 5. But i believe there is no more context to add.

Comment: The link doesn't work. Don't quote a sci-hub page. Give the original source. And give the explicit title and authors of the paper in your question.

Comment: $log \ R_p = b \ log \ I + log \ a \iff R_p = a I^b$.  So $a$ is the estimate of $R$ when $I=1$ and $b$ is an estimate of the slope on your log-log chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically , the Author might be saying like this :
The Experimental Curve was Initially given in "raw" terms where it was not easy to see the Empirical relation. Converting to "$log$ terms in $x$ Axis" or "$log$ terms in $Y$ Axis" still did not reveal the relation.
When the Converting to "$log$ terms in Both Axes" (that makes it $\log-\log$ Scale)  , the relation was linear $y=mx+c$ , where $y=\log(r)$ & $x=\log(I)$.
Standard regression & curve-fitting gave the linear relation values $m$ & $c$.

[image: PLOT]

I have written the $\log$ values on the Axes.
We can see that the green lines are very good approximations to the grey region.

Out of all the green lines , using "Best-fit" or other Math Criteria or even techniques within the Experimental Physics Community (or Photo-resistor Sub-Community) , the "Best" values were $m=−0.69$ & $c=10^{57.55}$.

In Photo-resistor terms , $b=m=−0.69$ & $a=\log(c)=\log(10^{57.55})=57.55$

[[ I am only answering the Thought-Process & the Math Technique , I am not a Physicist & hence I can not choose the "Best" & more-over, I have not verified the Claims & the Calculations made by the Author ]]

Comment: Thanks. It is starting to become clear now. I'm not good at math, and new to this kind of problems. If i see similar plot, what steps should i take to find this "Best-fit" line? Maybe you can advise math topics or techniques or some literature that explain this?

Comment: Try to check out the over-view "linear regression" [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression ] & the Particular technique "least squares" [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares ] & the general "curve fitting" [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting ] & ETC !

Comment: Cool. Thank you!

Comment: As an electronic engineer, I assure you that your solution is the correct one: and also the OP would be relevant also for the [EE.StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com). Essentially, putting $I=1$ you get rid of the first term in formula and the calculate the mean value of the values shown in diagram.

Comment: Thank you for confirming some aspects , @DanieleTampieri , which may add **Validity & Confidence** to this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\log = \log_{10}$, if you take the $\log$ of the labels on the axes, you get $0,1,2,3$ on the axes at equal distances, like the axes of a normal plot. The grey band 'plotted' is almost linear. So it's approximately a linear relation between $\log R_p$ and $\log I$. So if you linearly regress the $\log R_p$ data against $\log I$ data, you should get $b$ as slope and $\log a$ as y-intercept